# Using do while loop inside a foreach

Tags: php

I am doing this call to [soccer api](https://github.com/hristonev/sportmonks-client-bundle) inside a foreach loop to return each competition matches.
This call works just fine if it's outside a foreach loop.
When in foreach I only get the first competition array but then the array is not reseted! it keeps returning the same results for the first loop, I tried to unset the variables but that does not seem to work. any idea?

```
foreach($comps as $comp){
    $comp_api = $comp->comp_id;
    $from_date = new datetime($start_date);
    $to_date = new datetime($end_date);
    $matches_setup = ['query' => ['leagues' => $comp_id]];

    #loop matches
    $matches = array();
    do {
        $matches = array_merge($matches, $api->fixtures()->between()->period($from_date, $to_date, null, $matches_setup));
    } while ($monk_framework->fixtures()->nextPage($matches_setup));
    $results = $matches;

    /*
    * part where data is inserted to db
    */
}
```

Is there something wrong with how am doing it? or this could be an issue with the api?

Comment: Where does `$comp_id` come from and why loop `$comps` if you don't use `$comp`?  Maybe you want `$comp['id']` or something?

Comment: @AbraCadaver I clarified the code, I define it with a variable in the begging of the loop.

Comment: That is not a `do{ }while( );` loop it's just a `while(){  }` loop. There is a difference.  The do while loop always executes first then checks the condition, the while loop checks the condition first.   I can understand the mistake as `do while` is not used much. But, I thought wow someone is using a do while loop, then I was a bit disappointing.  They do have their uses but it niche in a way.

Comment: Should `$comp_api` be `$comp_id`?

Comment: `$start_date` and `$end_date` don't change during the loop, so there's no need to re-assign `$from_date` and `$to_date`. They can be set before the loop.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I am actually using a do...while it was a mistake of me adding old code here, now updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, and figured what was wrong.

```
while ($monk_framework->fixtures()->nextPage($matches_setup));
```

This part the params of nextPage used not to reset after each loop, it's a miss configuration in the api am using. resetting the params after each loop helped solve my issue.

```
#reset params for next call
self::$param = array();
```

For anyone who might stumble on this issue on the same [framework of sportmonks](https://github.com/hristonev/sportmonks-client-bundle), here is [full details](https://github.com/hristonev/sportmonks-client-bundle/issues/10) to the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are resetting your results on each loop.

You should append to results each iteration:

```
$results = [];

foreach($comps as $comp){

    $from_date = new datetime($start_date);
    $to_date = new datetime($end_date);
    $matches_setup = [
        'query' => [
            'leagues' => $comp_id
        ]
    ];

    #loop matches
    $matches = array();
    while ($api->fixtures()->nextPage($matches_setup)) {
        $matches = array_merge($matches, $api->fixtures()->between()->period($from_date, $to_date, null, $matches_setup));
    }
    $results = array_merge($results, $matches);
}
```

Comment: Thats not my issue, as I use $results inside the loop, I just clarified the code.

Comment: Be careful with merge, it's not the same as adding two arrays together depending on if the top level array has keys or not.  That said it's probably ok in this case. I've had some sticky situations with `array_merge` vs `array_replace` vs `$array + $array` in the past ... lol.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix If you look at the API documentation, it shows the use of `array_merge()`. So the data is apparently designed to be mergeable.

Comment: It's probably numeric indexed like a nested array from the DB, I just always cringe when I see array_merge ... lol ...